# Java String array getting all combinations based on n!/r!(n-r)!

Tags: java, arrays, string, recursion, combinations

I have tried to search about it, but have not found a definitive answer yet.
I am trying to write a program which compares a string array against all combinations of another string array, but these combinations have the same number of elements as the previous array.
To explain better, lets say I have two string arrays, n = {alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon} and r ={beta,gamma,delta}. 
Now what I want to do is, get all combinations (of three strings in each combination) from the set 'n' and compare the set 'r' against them all. If I get a match, then perform some action. 
I am aware that to get all combinations, I need to apply the formula,

```
                            nCr = n!/r!(n-r)!   (where 0<=r<=n)
```

in my case, n = 5, and r = 3, which gives 10 combinations in total. I need to generate all these combinations(10 in this case) and compare them against the array 'r'. I do not have a starting point yet, and I do not expect to get an answer but a little light towards how it can be implemented (will be probably done recursively?) would be great!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The formula only counts the number of combinations. It doesn't help you generate them all. So I suggest that you start with a simple example: What are all the combinations of 2 objects from the set {a, b, c, d}? (Hint: there should be 4*3/2=6 of them.)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you just trying to check if *n* contains all the elements of *r*? There are easier ways of doing that.

Comment: @Code-Guru : sorry, I edited my question. Yes, I do want to generate the combinations. and the answer to that would be (ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,cd)
Ok, I'm probably getting somewhere!

Comment: @miorel : I am trying to check if 'n' has a same combination of the same number of elements as that of 'r'

Comment: Now can you describe what steps you took to create that list? How would you use the list of combinations of two objects to create combinations of three objects?

Comment: So, as @miorel suggested, an easier way to answer the question is to check that n contains all the elements of r. You don't *really* need to generate the combinations to answer your question as stated.

Comment: Well, since in a combinations, mathematically speaking, order doesnt matter, so I need to just get the unique sets of each element with every other element.

Comment: This concept is part of the shop management system I am working on, where I am trying to implement the concept of discounted price for 'Offers'.
If the user buys 5 grocery items(bread, eggs, milk, meat, chicken), and as an offer, three of those items are saved under a discounted price(bread, eggs milk), the system should charge the discounted price for the three items, and the same for the other two. 
So for THIS I was trying to get the combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Given the additional context you've provided in the comments, here's what I'd suggest.

Turn *n* into a set for easier querying:

```
String[] n = {"alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "epsilon"};
Set<String> nset = new HashSet<String>();
nset.addAll(Arrays.asList(n));
```

Now you can check if it contains all the elements of *r*:

```
String[] r = {"beta", "gamma", "delta"};
if (nset.containsAll(Arrays.asList(r))) {
  // do something
}
```

This can be repeated with multiple different *r* arrays, and it will be more efficient than iterating over all the possible subsets of *n* and comparing them with a particular *r*.

Comment: This is a perfect solution, though will it work if I have duplicate values in the string array n?

Comment: Duplicate values in *n* are fine. If you need to match by count in *r* too then use a `Map<String,Integer>` with the count as the value instead of a `Set<String>`.